# In Angularjs, why am I getting an "Argument 'HomeController' is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a cordova app and want to use angular to build out pages a the user selects content. I'm building out in the web right now before I move to cordvoa.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="nanoApp">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngroute.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-script.js"></script>
</head> 

<body>

    <div id="content" class="scroller" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

angular-script.js:

```
var nanoApp = angular.module('nanoApp',['ngRoute']);

nanoApp
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'HomeController as homeSlides',
      templateUrl:'../content/home.html'
    });
});
```

home.html:

```
<div id="home" class="container paralax">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: You need to define HomeController, do you have it already, if so include that script in the html

Comment: Is there a `HomeController`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't define HomeController.

Try to create controller first

Like this

```
var nanoApp = angular.module('nanoApp',['ngRoute']);
nanoApp.controller("HomeController",["$scope",function($scope){
   //put your code here
}]);
```

Comment: this fixed the error but then the JS just stopped with no error. Not sure why, working that out